# Repetitions in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

For what $a, b$  there will be no repetitions in the sequence $\{x_n\}$:
$$\{a, a-b, 2a-b, 2a-2b, 3a-2b, 3a-3b, \ldots\}$$

My work:
It is like taking $a$ steps forward,  $b$ steps backward alternately.
This means after $2$ times doing this, the net result is $a-b$
so when the index is even, the sequence is given by
$$x_{2n} = n(a-b)$$

I'm really not sure where to go from here as there are two sequences mixed up here... Any help?

---

As an example, for $a=4, b=3$ the sequence fails(repetition of value)
$$4,1,5,2,6,3,7,4,...$$

for $a=4, b=1$ the sequence passes(no repetition):
$$4,3,7,6,10,9,\ldots$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The condition is:

There will be repetitions if and only if $a=b$ or $\dfrac{a}{a-b}\in \Bbb Z$.

$\Longrightarrow)$

If $x_n = x_m$ with $n\ne m$, then

- If $n=2k$, $m=2l$ with $k \ne l$. Then $k(a-b)=l(a-b)$ so $(k-l)(a-b)=0$. Since $k-l\ne 0$ we have $a=b$ and we're done.
- If $n=2k+1$, $m=2l+1$ with $k\ne l$. Then $a+x_{2k} = a+x_{2l}$, so $x_{2k} = x_{2l}$ and we're in the previous case.
- If $n = 2k$ and $m = 2l+1$ then $k(a-b)=a+l(a-b)$, so $(k-l)(a-b) = a$. If $a=b$, we're done. If $a\ne b$ then $\dfrac{a}{a-b}=k-l \in \Bbb Z$, and we're done again.

$\Longleftarrow)$

If $a=b$ then $x_2=0=x_4$.

If $\dfrac{a}{a-b}\in \Bbb Z$, then $\dfrac{a}{a-b}=m$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$. Then $a = m(a-b)$. That is $x_1 = x_{2m}$.

Comment: Interesting... thank you so much.. pretty sure you mean $$\frac{\color{red}{b}}{a-b}\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: @across I'm pretty sure is $\dfrac{a}{a-b}\in \Bbb Z$. Look at the proof.

Comment: Awesome! I did something similar but was working with $$x_{2n-1} = x_{2n}+\color{red}{b}$$... this gives the condition $$k-l = \frac{\color{red}{b}}{a-b}$$. This is identical to your condition $$\frac{a}{a-b} \in \mathbb{Z} \iff \frac{a}{a-b} -1 =  \frac{\color{red}{b}}{a-b}\in \mathbb{Z} $$. But  I see your approach is slick!